# Autocomplete on enter (but NOT in auto-select)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit, enter

I have a simple input field

and on enter I want to submit it (the form that it is in). I am using jQuery but not any autoComplete extension, so it's just the default browser one:

```
$('#searchfield')
.keypress(function(event) {
        var keycode;
        if (window.event)
            keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        else if (event)
            keycode = event.which;
        else
            return true;

        if (keycode == 13)
            $('#searchForm').submit();
});
```

**Problem with this solution:**
When somebody (in FF3) starts typing (say "stackov"), then goes arrow-down for the offered choice and hits enter, the form is sent off, albeit searching for "stackov", not for the chosen "stackoverflow".

*Alternatively I tried*

```
$('#searchfield')
.change( function() {
   $('#singleSearch').trigger('click');
})
```

That got me correct picking of "stackoverflow", but now *any* leaving of the field (as in blur(), after tapping some letters for example) involuntarily sent it off.

Any (ideally tested;) advice on this?

Comment: When you press up / down from your text box, are you filling the text box with the text of the suggestion? AKA: Press Down, Selects Suggestion, Fills Text box? Then when they press enter, the suggested text is present.

Comment: Are you using a form, or submitting this via AJAX?

Comment: Do you want it to submit while still editing the field or when the field is blurred? Your form should submit when enter is pressed anyway so long as your input is focused..

Comment: @Blender: submitting as a form.

Comment: @Calum: I want the auto-complete (arrow-down, arrow-down, enter) to just make the suggested term show up in the search bar (which is a browser-side feature anyway, I doubt I have much influence on this).  My problem is, that the sending-off happens too early... (or the enter-action I tied via jQuery to it, happens before the browser-internal enter action of filling the auto-complete-value into the input field...)

Comment: have you thought about using jQuery UI?http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, all I can say is, that a small delay to allow 'digest' of auto-complete before submit
fixes the issue:

```
if ((event.which && event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13)) {
    setTimeout( function() {
        $('#searchForm').submit(); 
    } , 30 );
};
```

Comment: I found setting the timeout to just `1` was still enough to allow the appropriate auto-complete behavior (FF4/Win).